# Parse the Entire Excel DataSource as a Feed to SOAP Request in SoapUI

Tags: xml, excel, soap, groovy, soapui

Is there a way to parse all the available rows in an Excel datasource of SoapUI Pro and feed it to a repeatable schema complex type of SOAP request other than programmatically reading it and inserting values into a SOAP request xml document with a Groovy script? i.e.:

```
       Col1  Col2  Col3
Row1   C11   C12   C13     
Row2   C21   C22   C23
Row3   C31   C32   C33
```

Into:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://my.ns.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
     <Rows>
       <Row>
         <Col1>C11</Col1>
         <Col2>C12</Col2>
         <Col3>C13</Col3>             
       </Row>
       <Row>
         <Col1>C21</Col1>
         <Col2>C22</Col2>
         <Col3>C23</Col3>             
       </Row>
       <Row>
         <Col1>C31</Col1>
         <Col2>C32</Col2>
         <Col3>C33</Col3>             
       </Row>
     </Rows>    
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was managed to write a script to do just that with the help of [JExcel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelapi/files/jexcelapi/2.6.12/) (unpack and place **jxl.jar** in soapui-installation-path/bin/ext) -- this assumes that your Soap request document contains everything except the *Row* elements:

```
import jxl.*;

def workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:\\Path\\To\\YourExcel.xls"))
def sheet = workbook.getSheet(0)

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "requestStep#Request" )
def rowsNode = holder.getDomNode("//Rows") // return a Rows Node
def updateRequestDoc = rowsNode.getOwnerDocument() // return a Document

// Clean up previous inserts
while (rowsNode.hasChildNodes()) {
   rowsNode.removeChild(rowsNode.getFirstChild())
}

// Skip the header
for (int i = 1; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) {
    Cell[] cells = sheet.getRow(i)
    if (cells.length > 0) {
        // Append Row node to the Rows Node
        def rowElement = updateRequestDoc.createElement("Row")
        rowsNode.appendChild(rowElement)

        // Populate the Row node with all the "available" cells for that row (blank elements are skipped)
        for (int j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
            String cellContent = cells[j].getContents()

            // Select the tag name based on the index in which it is parsed from the Excel document
            if (!cellContent.isEmpty()) {
                String tagName = null               
                switch(cells[j].getColumn()) {
                    case 0:
                        tagName = 'Col1'                    
                        break

                    case 1:
                        tagName = 'Col2'                        
                        break

                    case 2:
                        tagName = 'Col3'                        
                        break


                    default:
                        break

                }

                if (tagName != null && !tagName.isEmpty()) {

                    def currentElement = updateRequestDoc.createElementNS(tagName)
                    def currentTextElement = updateRequestDoc.createTextNode(cellContent)
                    currentElement.appendChild(currentTextElement)

                    // Get the last Row node and add the field element to it
                    def rowNode = rowsNode.getLastChild()
                    rowNode.appendChild(currentElement)
                }
            }
        }           
    }
}

holder.updateProperty(true)
workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

A datasource test step is intended to be read one line at a time, and used one line at a time. It can be done, but it would be difficult. You are essentially trying to fit a square peg into a round hole.

You would have to do something like:

1. DataSource
2. Groovy step that takes the current line from the DataSource and appends it to the Request (step 4). Google `XmlSlurper()` for idea how to do it.
3. Data Loop back to step 1.
4. Soap Request

Comment: That's actually a cleaner way of doing it. My code above, which should be an indicative that I am not a tester, does all that in one go, but I prefer yours. Thanks.